# Averages for 8-hour shifts in one row, grouped by days

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, join, group-by

I have a SQL Server table (tbl) with 2 columns: `ts` (timestamp) and `val` (value). I want to make a selection that gives back four columns: first is the day, the second is the average of the values from 10pm the preceding day till 6am, the third row is the average of the values from 6am till 2pm, and the fourth row contains the average of the stored values from 2pm till 10pm. So averages for 8-hour periods in a day which instead of midnight starts at the previous day at 10pm.

This is the query I have so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41334/2

I have the average for the whole 24-hour periods (from 10pm), but now I'm stuck. I was thinking that I could make 3 selections for the 8 hours periods and then join them on the day, but I don't know how or if at all I'm on the right track. Please help.

The result I would like to get using my example data:

```
DAY        | AVG_NITE | AVG_MORN | AVG_AFTN  
2014.12.07 | 3.75     | 5.6667   | 4.5714  
2014.12.08 | 4.6      | 5.6      | 5.4  
2014.12.09 | 5.5      | (null)   | (null)
```

Comment: how do you want to group the 8 hours period? which time frame to which time frame?

nvm its up there

Comment: I added to my question what I'd like to get as a result. The timeframe is 24 hours (from 10pm till the following day 10pm) where the averages would be calculated by 3 eight-hour periods.

Answer (score 2):

the code below produces desired ouput. it uses CTEs but you can change them to subqueries or Views.

```
WITH tbl2 AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(hour, 2, ts) AS ts2       
          ,val
    FROM tbl
)
, tbl_hours AS (      
    SELECT convert(varchar, ts2,102) AS [day] 
          ,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour,  cast(ts2 AS DATE), ts2)/8,0) AS period
          ,val
    FROM tbl2
)
SELECT
   [day]
  ,AVG( case when period = 0 then val else null end) AS [avg_nite]
  ,AVG( case when period = 1 then val else null end) AS [avg_morn]
  ,AVG( case when period = 2 then val else null end) AS [avg_aftn]
FROM tbl_hours
GROUP BY [day]
```

Comment: Thank you, teran. This works perfectly! As soon as I have enough points, I'll vote you up, and also lookslikeanevo. His answer is almost perfect, too, but for the day 2014.12.09 it doesn't give the right average for avg_nite.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select convert(varchar, dateadd(hour,2,ts), 102) as day,
avg(val) as avg_fullday
,avg(case when dateadd(day, -1, datepart(hour, ts)) in (22,23) 
            or DATEPART(hour, ts) in (0,1,2,3,4,5)
                then (val) end)'Nite'
,avg(case when DATEPART(hour, ts) in( 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
                then (val) end) 'Morn'
,avg(case when DATEPART(hour, ts) in (14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21) then (val) end) 'Aftn'







from #tbl
group by convert(varchar, dateadd(hour,2,ts), 102);
drop table #tbl
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be almost perfect! I've changed it a little bit because you added two columns the same name:  

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41334/39

I don't know why but at the last day the first average is incorrect. It should be 5.5 instead of 6.3333

Comment: Finally I've managed to fix your query. You mixed up dateadd and datepart in the first case. This is the final query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41334/48  Thank you to both of you. I learned a lot from the two solutions.

Comment: sorry just check back in now...glad you were able to sort through it.